# std::chrono::system_clock vs std::chrono::high_resolution_clock behavior

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

Consider the following code snippet:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
     auto result1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
     auto result2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
     assert((result2.count() - result1.count()) < 10);
}
```

I am expecting that the difference in counts between the two values should be minimal (ideally less than a second). But with VS2015, the difference in count is of the order of Billions of seconds. How is this possible?

Comment: The code, as shown, doesn't compile.

Comment: You need to include <chrono> and <cassert>

Comment: **Your code is not valid** a valid cast: `std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::seconds >( your-time )`

Comment: With `gcc 6.2.0` there is not error and both are the same

Comment: After making the [code compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ba688a4f54dc568) I get Identical results in g++ but I get `1806453` vs `1491565092` in MSVS 2017

Comment: Most likely it is a MSVS bug.  *what a shocker*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason it asserts for you is because `high_resolution_clock` is allowed to (and often does) have a different epoch than `system_clock`.

It is the de facto standard (not specified but portable) that `system_clock`'s epoch is measuring time since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, neglecting leap seconds<sup>1</sup>.

There is no de facto standard for `high_resolution_clock`.  On gcc `high_resolution_clock` is a typedef for `system_clock`, and so on gcc platforms, you'll notice perfect synchronization.  On VS and libc++ `high_resolution_clock` is a typedef for `steady_clock`.

For me, the epoch of `steady_clock` is whenever the computer booted up.

[Here is a video tutorial for `<chrono>`.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M)  It covers lots of issues, including this one, and is about an hour long.

---

<sup>1</sup> The de facto standard for `system_clock` [has been made official for C++20](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.system.overview#1).

> Objects of type `system_­clock` represent wall clock time from the
>   system-wide realtime clock. Objects of type `sys_­time<Duration>`
>   measure time since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC excluding leap seconds.
>   This measure is commonly referred to as [*Unix time*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). This measure
>   facilitates an efficient mapping between `sys_­time` and calendar
>   types ([time.cal]). [ *Example:*
>   `sys_­seconds{sys_­days{1970y/January/1}}.time_­since_­epoch()` is
>   `0s`.
>   `sys_­seconds{sys_­days{2000y/January/1}}.time_­since_­epoch()`
>   is `946'684'800s`, which is `10'957 * 86'400s`.
>   *— end example* ]